# In the ant task Exec why is <arg value="/c"/> provided for executable="cmd" ? what are the other possible executables?

Tags: ant, cmd, exec, task

In the ant task Exec why is  `<arg value="/c"/>` provided for executable="cmd"?
What are the other possible executables?
Could anyone please explain this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/c` is not an executable: it an argument to the executable (in this case "cmd.exe")

From the documentation (call "cmd /?" in a shell):

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
```